# Placing New Marker on Google Map - Function not being called on API 33 but works fine on API 31

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, sdk

I'm a beginner in android development and kotlin so pardon me if i ask anything too basic.

I'm working with google maps, and i'm trying to set a new marker for a location input by the user. This is done by my method `updateLocationOnMap(location: String, address: Address)`. `updateLocationOnMap` removes the previous Marker from the map and places the new one via `placeMarkerOnMap`. Everything works fine on a device running on API 31, but not for API 33, where `placeMarkerOnMap` does not even get called. I have tried troubleshooting with breakpoints as well, but everything works fine until the `placeMarkerOnMap(latLng, location)` line where the breakpoint does not even get hit. Here are the functions:

**updateLocationOnMap**

```
fun updateLocationOnMap(location: String, address: Address) {
        val latLng = LatLng(address.latitude, address.longitude)
        locationPanelBehavior?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED

        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) { // mCurrLocationMarker: Marker? 
            mCurrLocationMarker!!.remove() // this is called  for both API 31 and 33
        }
        placeMarkerOnMap(latLng, location) // this is not called when using API 33 emulator
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
}
```

**placeMarkerOnMap**

```
fun placeMarkerOnMap(currentLatLong: LatLng, location: String?) {
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(currentLatLong)
        val title = location ?: "Current Location"
        markerOptions.title(title)
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions)
}
```

Could this issue be due to the different SDK platforms? I'm sure it's not some arbitrary problem because this weird bug keeps happening. The emulators I'm using are Pixel 6 API 31 and Pixel 6 Pro API 33. Any help/suggestions will be much appreciated!